# running .x86_64 file on linux chromebook returns error: no such file or directory

Tags: chromebook, crostini

I am trying to run a linux game on my chromebook(the game can be found here https://bitbrain.itch.io/cave/download/eyJleHBpcmVzIjoxNjM3MjU1OTkwLCJpZCI6NzExNTc5fQ%3d%3d.hggqT%2fhX%2bV6ybeo2kdXBWZa4xCQ%3d) I have executed the following commands:
sudo su
/cave.x86_64

however, when I run the last command, I just get an error saying that no such file or directory exists. Please help me.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with; run the following to ensure that the commands you used aren't the problem

```sh
wget <download-link> -o cave-x86_64
chmod +x cave-x86_64
./cave-x86_64
```

If there are any errors, please add the full output, including what you enter

Comment: Thank you MOStudios, the commands I used were the problem, I ran the three you gave me and the program boted right up!

Comment: Happy it worked, I was wondering, could you also upvote the answer

Comment: I wish I could, but I joined maybe a week ago, so my reputation is under the required minumum to vote :(